# При запуске Android приложения жалуется на OkHttpServerBuilder.forPort()

Tags: java, grpc

При попытке запуска grpc сервера на Android приложение вылетает и в консоль выдаёт ошибку

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.forest.peredachafailov, PID: 4083
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:446)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1219)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1219) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpServerBuilder.forPort(OkHttpServerBuilder.java:87)
        at com.forest.peredachafailov.RemoteControl.main(RemoteControl.java:14)
        at com.forest.peredachafailov.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:19)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:441) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1219) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

RemoteControl.java

```
package com.forest.peredachafailov;

import com.forest.peredachafailov.grpc.Services;
import com.forest.peredachafailov.grpc.RemoteControlGrpc;

import java.io.IOException;

import io.grpc.Server;
import io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpServerBuilder;
import io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver;

public class RemoteControl extends RemoteControlGrpc.RemoteControlImplBase {
    public static void main() {
        Server server = OkHttpServerBuilder.forPort(8080).addService(new RemoteControl())
                .build();
        try {
            server.start();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            server.awaitTermination();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void greeting(Services.ImageRequest request,
                     StreamObserver<Services.ImageResponse> responseObserver) {

        Services.ImageResponse response = Services.
                ImageResponse.newBuilder().setImage("Image").build();

        responseObserver.onNext(response);

        responseObserver.onCompleted();

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.forest.peredachafailov;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        RemoteControl.main();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации класса `io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpServerBuilder`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/okhttp/OkHttpServerBuilder.html) указано, что [данный метод устарел и всегда выбрасывает исключение](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/okhttp/OkHttpServerBuilder.html#forPort-int-):

> @Deprecated
> `public static OkHttpServerBuilder forPort(int port)`
> **Deprecated**. Use [`forPort(int, ServerCredentials)`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/okhttp/OkHttpServerBuilder.html#forPort-int-io.grpc.ServerCredentials-) instead
> Always throws, to shadow `ServerBuilder.forPort()`.

и вместо него требуется использовать перегруженный метод с параметром `ServerCredentials`.

Поскольку `ServerCredentials` является абстрактным классом, нужно использовать какую-то из его реализаций `ChoiceServerCredentials, InsecureServerCredentials, TlsServerCredentials`, например: `InsecureServerCredentials.create()`.